# ORA-12541 error when deploying SSIS package to a server

Tags: oracle, ssis, oledb, ora-12541, dtexec

I am connecting SSIS to Oracle OLEDB connection using below connection string..

`Data Source=Server_Name;User ID=U_Id;Password=Pwd;Provider=MSDAORA.1;`

It works on my machine but when i run on SSIS server using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec` it gives me error: `ORA-12541: tns: no listener`

I tried playing around with file `tnsnames.ora` but did not get anywhere.

Comment: tried lsnrctl... got below error "Failed to open service <OracleOraHome112_32TNSListener>, error 1060."

Comment: What do you have under Package Configurations? Is your production server changing some values based on a different XML file or similar?

Comment: Try also to run the `dtexec` command with `/REPORTING V` option to get verbose output of the package execution.

Comment: Since the package works locally but not on the server, what are the differences between the two environments? Do they both have the same Oracle client and `tnsnames.ora` files? Does `tnsping Server_Name` work on the server? Is there any firewall between the server and the Oracle server?

Comment: @Pondlife on my machine (where connection works) I tried tnsping Server_Name and got below results.                              Used parameter files:
c:\apps\oracle\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias                        when tried same on ssis server   I got below 
Used parameter files:
C:\local\Oracle\clients\112_32\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias              here in the end i got our old error TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: @mceda .dtsconfig are a bit different but oracle connection string is same...

Comment: @Pondlife My machine is Windows 7 64 bit and prod is windows server 2008 64 bit

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, your Oracle client configuration is different on your workstation and on the SSIS server (because `$ORACLE_HOME` is different)? If so, you need to work out why they are different and make them the same; I don't know enough about Oracle to know what the problem is, but looking at `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` should give you some clues.

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify which Oracle installed directory on the server has the Oracle 32-bit drivers installed.  Oracle's Installer doesnt seem to offer any help for this - it's often quicker to uninstall the lot and start again.

The TNSNAMES.ORA you need to fix is in the NETWORK/ADMIN subdirectory below that Oracle 32-bit client installation.

I can't beleive it's 2012 (almost 2013) and we are still wrestling with this!

Comment: I notice bit difference regarding tnsnames on both machine…
On My machine 

tnsnames.oRA is at C:\Apps\oracle\Clients\112_32\network\admin\sample
and
tnsnames.ora is at C:\Apps\oracle\network\admin


On SSIS Server tnsnames.oRA is in below location

C:\local\Oracle\clients\112_32\NETWORK\ADMIN\SAMPLE

Does this hint anything regarding my problem?

Comment: Try copying your tnsnames.ora file to the server's C:\local\Oracle\clients\112_32\NETWORK\ADMIN directory

Answer (score 2):

At work we had to install the 64 bit oracle and then the 32 bit oracle if the machine was a 64bit machine for it to work.

For me locally this link helped a lot to get tnsnames working correctly. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_windows_tnsnames.ora_file_location.htm

Make sure the system variables has the path to tnsnames.ora otherwise apps don't appear to be able to connect.